# Cannot not install application from App Store on macos mojave

Tags: macos, applications, mojave, install, mac-appstore

I am a new Mac user and have purchased a Mac Pro 5,1 running Mojave to learn the basics of macOSX.

After some initial difficulty, I have logged on to the mac, created an appleid, added payment details, signed on to the (Macosx) app store and itunes under mojave.

In the apple App store I selected to install two free apps I use under MS-Windows: Microsoft OneNote and OneDrive. There were a whole array of problems trying to install this way. However, I have now got to the point where app store shows these two applications as "Purchased" but they are not installed on the mac. I have several times tried to redownload the apps but they do not install and no install materials appear in the Download folder. There are no diagnostic / error messages indicating a problem - just no installing occurs.

I cannot find on the mac the apps I have "purchased" (they are free but marked as "purchased" in App Store) in either the Applications folder or in the Launcher. The way I can describe the behaviour it is like I have had my order for the OSX applications accepted by App Store but they haven't been delivered to my mac pro.

I have rebooted the macPro about 4 times and retried the "installation" and nothing installs and there are no error messages from App Store.

Any ideas as how to fix?

Separately - and maybe relevant or not -  I **can** install apps from **outside** the app store but cannot install apps from inside the app store. For example, I went to the OBS website, downloaded the install package, ran it, and OBS is now installed and running on the mac - easy.

Thanks.

Comment: "Purchased" is an odd designation. If you click your name, bottom left of the main window in App Store, you should see either a button marked 'Open' or a Cloud icon with a downward arrow [depending on whether the app is on your Mac right now or needs to be [re]downloaded. Once an app is downloaded it will be in Applications [not Downloads] & also in the Launcher [Rocket icon in the Dock]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I clicked the cloud with the arrow about thee times earlier today and I get a spinning circle and nothing else - no downloads - no application.

Comment: This icon - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBg6L.png - which starts as a grey circle & gradually fills to blue as it downloads - or do you get a multi-coloured spinning cursor [the busy cursor]?

Comment: Thanks. On the "purchased" screen after I click on my account name in bottom-left corner of the mac App store screen ,  there is a blue cloud with a blue arrow pointing down next to each application. I click on the cloud/arrow and a pale grey circle starts spinning. One generated the message (something like) "There was a problem. Download cancelled" or the circle spins indefinitely . I have checked my credit card details entered in my apple account three times today. I thought I would never write the following "this whole process is a whole lot easier under Windows".

Comment: Actually - the process [if you don't hit any issues] is what Windows eventually copied from Apple, who first started this 20 years ago ;-)) However, that doesn't help you. I do get the feeling Apple's servers are going to be massively swamped right now - iOS & iPadOS 14 just came out yesterday, so my first thought is to see what happens if you wait it out… which again I'm aware doesn't help you right now. Alternatives could be fiddly. Sign out of everything, reboot everything [from Mac to router] sign back in… do the hokey cokey [sorry;)

Comment: The error text is "we could not complete your purchase. cancelled"

Comment: Ahh. That's probably something you're going to have to ring Apple for. If you've the patience, wait til tomorrow, try 'purchasing' something else that's free, see what happens. If the same, i'd give them a call. I've only ever had to ring them a couple of times in 30 years - they're helpful  & friendly & can see behind the scenes [if not rocket scientists] They'll call you back wherever you are in the world, in the language you specify. I've called them from 'foreign countries' & spoken to someone in English within 5 mins, who fixed my issue right there. https://www.apple.com/contact/

Comment: @tetsujin Thanks for all your time and suggestions. i have opened up a question to Apple and the response has passed me on to someone else. I will update this thread when I get a fix or fail. Good point their servers maybe swamped at the moment. If only I could find a non-app store source of the install resources ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Catalina using the ["Dosdude1 Catalina patcher"](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/). The Mac Pro 5,1 (ex 4,1) boots, is stable and I have successfully downloaded 3 software applications from App store. What an amazing achievement that patcher is.